SHAP value explanations in binary classification
I was trying to interpret my binary classification model using the SHAP value for each feature. I am wondering:
Does the positive SHAP value mean the feature contributed more to predicting the "1" class and the negative SHAP value mean the feature contributed more to predicting the "0" class?
and what if I use absolute SHAP value difference to describe the feature contribution changes is this idea legit?

If you're looking at summary plot, you see mean(abs(SHAP values)). Pay attention to what's written at the bottom of the plot.

First, you will need to clarify if the SHAP values are (A) on probability scale, or (B) on logit(probability) scale, or (C) on something else. We cannot know because your question is very vague.

its the value directly from the SHAP package, I assume its prob scale?

Yep you are absolutely right, the more positive value the more probability to be a 1, and the more negative value the higher probability to have a 0.
As for your ideai regarding comparing ith the SHAP absolute values you are absolutelly correct  here.
Check this article for more details Using SHAP Values to Explain How Your Machine Learning Model Works
